# start auto refresh page with click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a update panel that contain gridview i wanna this page be auto update. i wrote fallowing snippet but my problem that when i locate this code in document.ready its work Properly
but when i locate it in on click of button it dont work
its my code;

```
   var temp;
    $(document).ready(function () {
            var refreshId = setTimeout(function () {
             if (temp == 1) {
                $('#menu').load('WebForm11.aspx');
                }
            }, 5000);
    });

    function Button2_onclick() {
        temp = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try SetInterval insteadof SetTimeout

```
var temp;
    $(document).ready(function () {
            var refreshId = SetInterval(function () {
             if (temp == 1) {
                $('#menu').load('WebForm11.aspx');
                }
            }, 5000);
    });

    function Button2_onclick() {
        temp = 1;
    }
```

Comment: i try it before.Does not matter